# How can I update local html file after adding new element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am new to web development.
I am try to add a list item to a unorded list.
using javascript

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Item Add Test</title>
    <script src="item.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="item.css">
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="initem"></input>
<br /><br />
<button onclick="myFunction1()" id="submit">SUBMIT</button>

<ul id="menu">
    <li>ABC</li>
    <li>BLA</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

css item.css

```
body {
    font-family: monospace;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

input {
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#submit {
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

javascript item.js

```
function myFunction1() {
    var name = document.getElementById("initem").value;
    var node = document.createElement("LI");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(name);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("menu").appendChild(node);
}
```

I successfully add items to the list.
But when I refresh the page all items are gone.

How can I save the html file or update the html file after adding the items,so that if I refresh the page list items remain there.

Comment: Clientside JavaScript can not save the file on the server. You would need to use a serverside language to do it. If you want to store it just for the current browser, you can use local storage.

Comment: can you show me this with php?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the text of `<li>` elements in the local storage and retrieve on `load` event of the body.
The snippet won't work for security reasons but I tried on Sublime Text and it's fine.

```js
var li_texts = [];

function myFunction1() {
    var name = document.getElementById("initem").value;
    var node = document.createElement("LI");
    var text = 'Test';
    node.innerHTML = text;
    document.getElementById("menu").appendChild(node);
    li_texts.push(text);
    localStorage.setItem("li_texts", JSON.stringify(li_texts));
    
}

function loadList(){
  
  if (localStorage.getItem("li_texts") !== null) {
    var stored_names = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("li_texts"));
    

    for(i=0; i<stored_names.length; i++){
      var node = document.createElement("LI");
      node.innerHTML = stored_names[i];
      document.getElementById("menu").appendChild(node);

  
    }
  }
  else{
    return;
  }

}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: monospace;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

input {
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#submit {
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Item Add Test</title>
    <script src="item.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="item.css">
</head>
<body onload="loadList()">
  <input type="text" id="initem"></input>
  <br /><br />
  <button onclick="myFunction1()" id="submit">SUBMIT</button>

  <ul id="menu">
    <li>ABC</li>
    <li>BLA</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```